# how to stop refreshing page on button click using master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

1.i am using master page and webform in insert one form tag but when 
   2.  i use this update panel is not working
         on button click page refreshing problem'

```
<form id="form_sample_1" class="form-horizontal"
   runat="server"onsubmit="submitForm();">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptmanager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpDateGrid" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>


    <asp:Button ID="btnSaveInstitute" runat="server" 
     Text="Save"  OnClick="btnSave_Click" CausesValidation="false"></asp:Button>

    </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSaveInstitute"  />
     </Triggers>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide event name to the trigger..Provide `EventName="Click"` as it is a button..

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpDateGrid" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSaveInstitute" runat="server" 
     Text="Save"  OnClick="btnSave_Click" CausesValidation="false"></asp:Button>
    </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSaveInstitute" EventName="Click" />
     </Triggers>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have not provided `EventName` of Control:

```
<Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSaveInstitute" EventName="Click"  />
</Triggers>
```

See [**Here**](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) more Details.

Comment: when i insert event namethan  display this msg
Could not find an event named 'btnSave_Click'

Comment: you have to provide event name is it ``click`` or is it ``change`` not the event method that is called

Comment: In this case you need to write ``EventName="Click"``